# How to connect databricks SQL notebook to a parquet file via filepath

Tags: ssms, databricks, parquet, azure-databricks

I'm trying to connect to a list of parquet files that contain our data tables, I need to retrieve them to create a new table within a databricks notebook that will have the following fields:

- Field Name
- Data Type
- Table Name

I just need to know the syntax for connecting to these parquet files via sql in a databricks notebook and any help with setting up these fields to display data as if pulling from information_schema in SSMS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below syntax will help you to create table using given parquet file path:

```
%sql 
CREATE TABLE <Table_Name>
USING parquet
OPTIONS (path "</path/to/Parquet>")
```

Change the `<Table_Name>` and `</path/to/Parquet>` with your values.

You can read the data by using SELECT statement:

`SELECT * FROM <Table_Name>`

Apache Spark also enables us to easily read and write Parquet files to Azure SQL Database.

```
df.write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://{servername}.database.windows.net;databaseName={databasename};")
  .option("dbtable", "{tablename}")
  .option("user", {localusername})
  .option("password", {localpassword})
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .option("customSchema", "sqlschemadetails")
  .save()
```

We have to specify the JDBC connection string including SQL user name and password along with the schema name.

Useful link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ingest-data-to-azure-sql-database-using-azure-databricks/

You can open Azure SQL Server database on SSMS simply by using servername, user and password as shown below.

[image]